# why in-wheel BLDC motor have more pole than normal BLDC motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor, electric-machine, magnetic-flux

I am using a In-wheel BLDC Motor having poles 46 but another normal BLDC motor have less pole as 8 pole. I have searched about other In-wheel BLDC motor and it also have 42 poles.

Comment: No gears, so slower speed. To keep acceptably high frequency more poles are used.

Comment: Normal motor also have not any gear. You can see in given link that a normal motor having 8 pole has speed 4000 rpm=419 rad/s. It is a huge speed. http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/344007/TRINAMIC/QBL4208.html

Comment: A car with a regular BLDC motor has gears between the motor and the wheels. The wheels don't spin at 4000 rpm.

Comment: In-wheel motors have don't gear.

Comment: @τεκ Sounds like something that should be an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: In-wheel motors don't spin at 4000 RPM. More poles, less speed.

Answer (score 4):

In-wheel motors have lots of poles so that they can operate effectively at low rotational speeds.

Think about pretty much any bare "electric motor" you see.  They usually go whizzing around at normal operating speeds.  This is why gear heads on electric motors are common.  They give you high torque at the slower speed you actually want, while allowing the motor design speed to be a much more convenient higher speed.

For direct-drive in-wheel operation, there is no option for a gear box.  The motor has to run at the wheel speed.  Even at highway speeds for typical cars, that's still quite slow for electric motors.

Lots of poles allows the magnetic cycle speed to be fast - that's actually what matters - while the shaft speed is lower.  With 46 poles, for example, the electrical and magnetic speed is 46 times higher than the mechanical shaft rotation speed.

This is not usually done because lots of poles increases manufacturing complexity and cost.  In most applications, gear boxes are a better tradeoff.  Put another way, lots of poles is plan B when plan A (gearbox) can't be used.

Comment: Can I use DC Motor emf equation to explain the speed and poles relationship? E=(NPφZ)/(60*A)      where N is speed, P is poles, Z is number of conductor, A is number of parallel path.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the amount of power a motor can produce is equal to the amount of work done per magnetic cycle, times the number of cycles per second.  A motor that cycles twice as fast as another need only generate half as much work per cycle to produce the same power output.

Comment: @supercat that relationship only makes sense if you are talking about increasing the cycles on the same motor. Doubling the pole count might double the cycles, but it is no longer the same motor. The torque/efficiency cannot be increased by increasing the pole count (as a first order effect).

Comment: @Jon: The easiest way of doubling the cycle count for a given output speed is usually--as Mr. Lathrop noted--to add a gear box, and in that case one would be using the same motor.  Adding more poles, as may be necessary in cases where a gearbox would be impractical, makes things more complicated, which is part of why gearboxes are a preferred approach in most cases.

Comment: @supercat the issue is that you can't change the cycle rate without affecting the per cycle energy transfer using pole count. With a gearbox you can. If you double the number of poles the amount of winding around each new pole is halved. This halves the force per pole. Additionally, each pole moves half the distance per cycle. So the work per pole per cycle is 1/4 of before. But there are twice as many poles, and twice as many cycles. The net effect is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The reason a direct drive wheel motor has more poles is to reduce the weight of the motor.

If you have less poles, the flux return path for the motor (the iron ring behind the magnets and the iron linking the pole teeth) needs to be thicker, so the motor weighs more. If you have too many poles, eddy current losses in the steel start increasing quickly. Also, at some point the remaining pole tooth iron is going to dominate the motor mass and further reductions in backing iron will become increasingly less effective while adding more poles increases manufacturing costs.

Note, adding more poles *does not* increase the amount of torque the motor can produce for a given rotor diameter. There is no 'magnetic gearing' effect for surface magnet motors. This is different from reluctance switching structures such as hybrid step motors which can generate magnetic gearing (torque increasing as pole count rises).

Comment: But rare earth magnet (NdFeB) are more costlier than steel(Iron).

Comment: @aman2909 the thickness of the magnets does not change. Just the steel ring that provides the return flux path behind then.

Comment: Sir,  I want to say that if I increased the number of poles that means we have require more magnet. So the cost is more. Instead of increasing cost of magnet why not chose steel, which have less cost.   Or you want to say that, since magnetic strength required is same, so that the thickness of magnet is same. Only, magnet number is increased to reduce the each magnet thickness.

Comment: @aman2909 more magnets but they are each smaller. The total volume of magnet material does not change.

Comment: Thanks sir.   Can you solve my other question that how to estimate speed of in-wheel BLDC motor since commercial available in-wheel BLDC motor don't have any encoder. In my thesis work I want to use speed feedback.